# How to stop hGetLine from stripping the trailing newline

Tags: haskell

When I use `hGetLine` the returned string is missing the trailing ‘\n’.

Is there a way to stop `hGetLine` from stripping the trailing newline?

Comment: Have you tried using `hGetContents`? Otherwise I would use `fmap (<>"\n") hGetLine` to insert the newline character

Comment: Won’t `hGetLine` also return in the case of `EOF`, in which case I will add a \n when I shouldn’t? Will look into `hGetContents`. Thanks.

Comment: `hGetContents` slurps all the input, in some cases you don't want that. Anyway, `hGetLine` will not return on EOF: it will throw an exception. From a  quick test, I found no way to detect the very last newline in a text file using only `hGetLine`.

Comment: @chi AFAIK it will throw an exception only if EOF is the first character of the line. Otherwise it just returns normally.

Comment: @599644 Correct. That's why it seems there's no way to detect whether the last line has a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop hGetLine from stripping the trailing newline?

No, there is not. It's simply part of `hGetLine` the source code [1].

**Solution:**

Depending on your use case you might choose alternative approach like appending the `"\n"` back manually (imho not nice) or using `readFile` [2], `hGetContents` [3] or one of from similar functions or even using completely different solution.

Note, that both mentioned functions are lazy.

--

[1] http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Text.html#hGetLine

[2] http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readFile

[3] http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetContents